Reledmac and babel IAST transliteration
Following up on the following response to another question: Is Reledmac compatible to babel's IAST transliteration? Some first experiments suggest otherwise:
\documentclass{memoir}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms=transliteration.iast]{sanskrit}
\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}



\usepackage{reledmac}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{\leftmargin}
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}
\setstanzapenalties{1,10000,5000,10000,0}
\numberstanzatrue
\renewcommand{\stanzanumwrapper}[1]{}
\newcounter{stanzanum}
\Xstanza
\Xstanzaseparator[A]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[B]{}
\Xstanzaseparator[C]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[D]{.}
\Xarrangement[]{paragraph}


\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{sanskrit}


\beginnumbering
\linenumberstyle{arabic}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{3}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{3}
\pstart
\begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit}
\textbf{surasattama}-ityādi: he \textbf{surasattama}! tridaśaśreṣṭha!
\textbf{somālā} sukumārā, ārdrasvabhāvā.
\edtext{kāsau}{\Cfootnote{em.; kāso L.}}?
\edtext{prajety}{\Cfootnote{em.; prajity L.}} aparārdhe
vakṣyati.
prajety aparārdhe vakṣyati.
\end{otherlanguage}
\pend
\endnumbering


\end{document}

LuaLaTeX seems to be compiling the actual text, but when it comes to the critical apparatus below, seems to get stuck.  I can force the end of compilation by pressing enter for a number of times. Missing characters are reported, and I get only boxes. Furthermore, the \edtext{}{} command breaks the feature of the deletion of undesired postconsonantal spaces.



I’m on it. But a couple of comments: (1) you are setting Noto Serif Davanagari as the only font, but it doesn’t contain any Latin character. (2) The arguments of \edtext are saved and moved outside the environment, to a place where english is in force. The combination of these factors explains the empty boxes.

At least for testing purposes, setting the main language of the document to Sanskrit should indeed be an option, but, being new to babel, I haven't figured out the way to do that. \babelprovide[import,main,transforms=transliteration.iast]{sanskrit} does not seem to do the trick. In practice however, I would normally keep English as the main language of the document, and use Sanskrit in Devanāgarī script only for the edition part of the book. In fact, within the parts of the project which would be in English, whenever I use Sanskrit, I would use IAST.

When preparing an example, I’ve found a nasty bug. Sadly, right now I’m very busy, but I hope to be able to fix it in the next few days.

With babel 24.15, just released, which fixes a bug related to unboxed stuff (e.g., \unhbox, used internally by reledmac).
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms=transliteration.iast]{sanskrit}
% == Main font and Davanagari font ==
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}  
\babelfont[*devanagari]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{\leftmargin}
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}
\setstanzapenalties{1,10000,5000,10000,0}
\numberstanzatrue
\renewcommand{\stanzanumwrapper}[1]{}
\newcounter{stanzanum}
\Xstanza
\Xstanzaseparator[A]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[B]{}
\Xstanzaseparator[C]{.}
\Xstanzaseparator[D]{.}
\Xarrangement[]{paragraph}

% == To switch to Sanskrit quickly ==
\newcommand\sa[1]{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\linenumberstyle{arabic}
\setcounter{firstlinenum}{3}
\setcounter{linenumincrement}{3}
\pstart
\begin{otherlanguage}{sanskrit}
\textbf{surasattama}-ityādi: he \textbf{surasattama}! tridaśaśreṣṭha!
\textbf{somālā} sukumārā, ārdrasvabhāvā.
\edtext{\sa{kāsau}}{\Cfootnote{em.; kāso L.}}?
\edtext{\sa{prajety}}{\Cfootnote{em.; prajity L.}} aparārdhe
vakṣyati.
prajety aparārdhe vakṣyati.
\end{otherlanguage}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}



